# How to group excluded from source control files (TFS, Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is it possible to group them to a folder (or workitem) or something similar, and how?

edit: 
I am asking because sometimes when working on a task I need to jump to another and check in only the other task changes and exclude all others. Later when I get back to the first one I want to be able to resume the work in progress. It is OK if I only jump between two tasks, but if there are 3 and more changes (on a particular task) cannot be tracked fast.
I searched SO but did not find answer, also vs ui does not seem to provide the option.
Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, 
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 15.117.26714.0

Comment: Could you explain a bit more of what you're trying to do? Showing what it does right now, how it's not helping you and explaining what you'd like to see helps. Plus, I assume this is for TFVC source control? Which version of TFS? Which version of VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not a recommend way in TFS. It's not the really usage of excluded list.You should use **Shelveset** instead.

Sometimes you need to set aside some or all of your work in progress. Shelvesets are useful when you want to stop work for:

> - **Interruption:** You have pending changes that are not ready for check    in, but you need to work on a different task.
> - Collaboration: You have pending changes that are not ready for check in but you need to share them with another team member.
> - ..

You could simply suspend and resume your work from the **My Work** page, more details please refer this tutorial--[**Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!